# How to enable JVM metrics on Heroku hosted app deployed via "heroku deploy:jar ..." command

Tags: java, git, heroku

I have an app deployed on Heroku.

I used the following command [heroku deploy:jar](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-executable-jar-files#using-the-heroku-java-cli-plugin) to deploy it::

```
heroku deploy:jar my-heroku-app-name.jar --team=my-team --app=my-heroku-app-name
```

The app is deployed and running successfully.

I now want to enable [Heroku JVM Runtime Metrics](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/language-runtime-metrics-jvm). The [instructions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/language-runtime-metrics-jvm#getting-started) tell me to run the following commands:

```
git commit --allow-empty -m "Enable Heroku Metrics"
git push heroku master
```

I think these instructions are based on the assumption that I have a local git repository representing my deployed application AND my shell current working directory is within that repository. I have no such repository (as I deployed via deploy:jar), so I thought I should clone a local git repository from the Heroku git respository.

I tried to use this [technique](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-clone-heroku-app) to clone a local git repo from the Heroku master. However I when I try this I get:

```
$ heroku git:clone -a my-heroku-app-name
Cloning into 'my-heroku-app-name'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
```

Which I guess is expected because:

> You cannot clone your app’s source from Heroku if you deploy your app with any method besides git push. Other deployment methods do not update your app’s Heroku Git repo, causing heroku git:clone to return an empty repository. These other deployment methods include:
>
> Deploying directly from GitHub
>   Heroku Container Registry
>   The Heroku Button

I also tried following the instructions, even though I got the "You appear to have cloned an empty repository" warning in the middle, this is the commands and output:

```
$ heroku git:clone -a my-heroku-app-name
Cloning into 'my-heroku-app-name'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.

$ cd my-heroku-app-name/

$ git status
On branch master

No commits yet

nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)

$ git commit --allow-empty -m "Enable Heroku Metrics"
[master (root-commit) 34534df] Enable Heroku Metrics

$ git push heroku master
Enumerating objects: 2, done.
Counting objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 179 bytes | 179.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 2 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: pathspec '.' did not match any file(s) known to git.
remote: 
remote: !   Heroku Git error, please try again shortly.
remote: !   See http://status.heroku.com for current Heroku platform status.
remote: !   If the problem persists, please open a ticket
remote: !   on https://help.heroku.com/tickets/new
remote: !   and provide the Request ID zzzzzzzzzzzzz
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/my-heroku-app-name.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/my-heroku-app-name.git'
```

I also tried this but that did not seem to help either:

```
$ heroku labs:enable "runtime-heroku-metrics" -a "my-heroku-app-name"
Enabling runtime-heroku-metrics for my-heroku-app-name... done
```

I see this in the Heroku Console Metrics tab:

> Not Receiving JVM Metrics: We are not currently receiving JVM Runtime Metrics data from your application.

What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried to redeploy with `heroku deploy:jar my-heroku-app-name.jar --team=my-team --app=my-heroku-app-name`? You don't need to redeploy with git to enable metrics.

Comment: @Malax, thanks. That fixed it. Can you please submit that as the answer, is there a link to this in the docs that I missed?